# Nancy - Super Simple View Engine : Nested @Each

Tags: nancy

Does SSVE support nested iterators?

I am looking to walk down an object graph in my SSVE view (see below) but I suspect that nested iterators are not the way to go here. Is there another approach?

I know SSVE was intended for internal use and is not meant for full production use, so no problems, but I don't want to add an reference to Razor and mess up my web.config file unless I absolutely have to.

**Nested Iterator View (my best guess)**

```
@Master['_Master']

@Section['Content']
    <h1>Assessment - @Model.survey.title</h1>
    @Each.survey.pages 
        <div>
            <h2>@Current.title</h2>
            @Each.questions
                <div>@Current.title</div>
            @EndEach
        </div>
    @EndEach
@EndSection
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question is quite old now, but still crops up as the top search result on Google for nested each using the Super Simple View Engine. In case anyone else runs into this, know that support for Partial Views within an Each has been added to SSVE. (I've used it to do exactly this kind of View nesting - iterating over collections within collections.)

So you can achieve the effect you want using two Views, where the outer one looks like this:

```
@Master['_Master']

@Section['Content']
    <h1>Assessment - @Model.survey.title</h1>
    @Each.survey.pages 
        <div>
            <h2>@Current.title</h2>
            @Partial['QuestionList', Current.questions]
        </div>
    @EndEach
@EndSection
```

And then the other View (which SSVE will find with the name QuestionList) looks like this:

```
@Each
    <div>@Current.title</div>
@EndEach
```

Though it leads to quite a few files, you should be able to get to arbitrary depth by repeating this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work - SSVE is essentially just a regex. It *should* support a partial inside an each, but currently it doesn't.

Comment: A nested @Partial would do the trick right enough ... and would lead to a clever separation-of-concerns with respect to views. You are obviously a busy man but do you have any plans to get this working?

Comment: Plans, yes, time, no :-P I was hoping to get it into the next Nancy release, but I'm not 100% sure if I'll be able to.

Comment: Has any progress been made on this missing feature? I'm hoping this feature was added and that this question just needs an updated.

Comment: @Detroitpro I believe TheCodeJunkie got this working yesterday .. it's not in master yet though.